# How to "catch" highlighted text with script?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, selection

I'd like to write a script that sits idle and executes upon some keypress. This script would "catch" the user's highlighted text and do something with it (write it to an excel file, pass it to a dictionary, etc.)

My initial thought was to put the code in `catch.sh` file, highlight a word, and run the script. But I don't know how to pass the highlighted word as a parameter.

How could I write a script that takes the highlighted word as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach for this is to use /Applications/Automator.app to create a Service. The Service can be implemented in terms of a shell script by using the Run Shell Script action, or it can use a multitude of other available actions that may be even simpler.

Services are available in the application menu and right-click/Control-click contextual menu. The user can assign a key combination to invoke a Service, in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts tab > Services list element.

In addition to just receiving text, a Service can return text, if you want, which will replace the selection in the app from which it was invoked. That allows a Service to transform the selected text.